# Should I handle a mongoose connection with .then or .on?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm not sure if I should handle a mongoose connection as a promise or event. `(Console.log("Successfully connected")`

I think they can be used interchangeably, but I'm curious if there are benefits using it as an event with `.on` compared to handling it as a regular promise. If there are no benefits, I think I'll continue using what I find more comfortable, and maybe do a bit more research in the performance difference (I know the performance difference is not that significant but it doesn't hurt to try to use the most optimum method to handle the connection response)

Comment: Events can happen more than once. Promises are only resolved once.

Comment: Well, deciding whether to use `.then` or `.on` is like trying to choose between pizza or burgers - both can be satisfying, but it ultimately depends on your personal preference and the context of the situation!

Answer (score 0):

Either .then or.on handlers in Mongoose may be used to respond to a successful connection to a MongoDB database. Use.then instead since it is more understandable and adheres to the Promise-based design pattern.

To deal with a connected Mongoose, consider the following usage of.then:

Here, we'll use mongoose as an example. After passing in the MongoDB endpoint and any other connection parameters, we use.then to deal with a successful connection by writing a message to the console. We detect connection failures to MongoDB and report them to the console.

Moreover, the.on function may be used to deal with a successful Mongoose connection:

Here, we see how to utilise the.on function to keep an ear out for the 'connected' event that is generated when Mongoose establishes a connection to a MongoDB repository. When this event occurs, a log entry is made in the console.

Both methods are functional, but.then is preferable because to its readability and consistency with the Promise-based design pattern.

Comment: Reading your response reassures me on my decision to handle a connection as a promise, but would .on constantly be listening for a connected event? or would mongoose stop it in the background?

Comment: I just read node.js event emitter dev article, and .once only listens once, and .on willconstantly listens, so it should be fine if I use .once